# Use SendKeys to 'type' a variable in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Can SendKeys type a variable? for example

```
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set TypeThis = I Want it to type whats here
ws.SendKeys [I want it to type the variable(TypeThis]
ws.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.sleep 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass a variable to the `SendKeys` method as an argument. When you want to assign a value to a variable you should not use the keyword `set`. Use it only when you want to assign a reference to an object.

```
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
typeThis = "I Want it to type whats here"
ws.SendKeys typeThis
WScript.sleep 1000
```